# How to display rows from MySQL not older than a day?

Tags: mysql, joomla

I want to display news, for example from yesterday. Here's what my query looks like. Is there any magical line of code which would do that?

```
$query = '
    SELECT a.*, 
           CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN  CONCAT_WS(":", a.id, a.alias)
                                          ELSE a.id END as slug,
           CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(b.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", b.id, b.alias) 
                                          ELSE b.id END as catslug,
           b.title as category_title, 
           b.alias as categoryalias, 
           b.params as categoryparams,
           u.name AS author
    FROM #__content as a 
    LEFT JOIN #__categories as b ON a.catid = b.id
    LEFT JOIN #__users AS u ON u.id = a.created_by
    WHERE ' . $where. ' 
    ORDER BY ' . $orderby. ' 
    LIMIT ' . $limit;
```

Comment: What's in your `$where` variable? And what's your date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "magical" line of code should be in your WHERE clause.

e.g. if you date is only YYYY-MM-DD

```
$query .= 'WHERE b.created_date = '.$db->quote( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) ).'
```

e.g. if your date column is YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s

```
$query .= 'WHERE DATE_FORMAT(b.created_date,"%Y-%m-%d") = '.$db->quote( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) ).'
```